# how to find iso-cost contours on a 2d plot efficiently

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

Consider a 2D plot in which dimension 1 and 2 represent quantity 1 and 2 respectively ranging over 0 to 100. Each point in the space corresponding to (x,y) represent cost of choosing quantity 1 as x and quantity 2 as y. Assume cost increases monotonically with increase in quantities. I want to find iso-cost lines(contours) in the space. Say all those points whose cost is equal to some K. How do I find it efficiently without checking cost of all the points in the space which is 100 cross 100.?

Answer (score 0):

It is an optimization-problem. It can be solved with the lagrangian-method.

$min \ \ L=K(x,y)-\lambda(100-x-y)$

Now calculate the following derivations and set them all zero:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x  }=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial y }=0,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda }=0$

Then solve the system of 3 variables and 3 equations.

greetings,

calculus

Comment: thanks for your reply..how did u get this term               −λ(100−x−y)

Comment: It is the constraint, which says, that the sum of two quantities, x and y, must be 100. It could be for example x=30 and y=70. But the concrete values are determinated by the optimization. I hope I have understood  the situation right.

Comment: there is no constraint like that. x can be say 65 and y can be 70, f(x,y) can be some K. Also we only know that cost increases monotonically wrt quantities

Comment: O.K. You can first assume a cost funktion like this: $K=x^a\cdot y^b$ with $ a,b \geq 0$ Solve it for y and assume for $a,b$ and $K$ concrete values. The budget line is in general $x+y=c, \forall x,y \leq 100$. Just draw some budget lines which touches some iso-cost lines (curves). Only one budget line for one iso-cost line.

Comment: kindly check out this link                                                   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845641/how-to-find-iso-function-value-points-without-exploring-all-points-in-2d-space

Answer (score 0):

The magic words are [Marching Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares).

Basically, you walk through all the vertices in your mesh marking 0 if below threshold, 1 if above.  Then for each rectangle you have four bits determining if the points are above/below threshold.  These bits form an index (0-15) with which you can look up a set of contour line segments for each square.  Accumulating all the contour segments for all the squares yields the contour plot.  You probably want to linearly interpolate the location of the segment endpoints rather than just setting the location at the midpoint of the edge.